# Why is the Kleene star of a null set is an empty string?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

The [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Examples) and [textbooks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/113318779X) mention that,

$\emptyset^\star = \{\epsilon\}$

> The star operation puts together any number of strings from the
>   language to get a string in the result. If the language is empty, the
>   star operation can put together 0 strings, giving only the empty
>   string.

*(Taken from page 65 of the above mentioned textbook.)*

Now the logic behind this somewhat escapes me. How come a null set when taken zero times can give you an empty string?

To begin with, a null set has only zero strings. But a set with an empty string
has one string with zero length.

Could somebody please explain this with real life examples?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By definition, the strings in $X^*$ (for any language $X$, whether $X = \emptyset$ or not) are those constructed by taking some finite number (possibly $0$) of strings from $X$ and concatenating them.

If you take $0$ strings and concatenate them, you get $\epsilon$.  Note that this has nothing to do with whether $X=\emptyset$ or not. The empty string $\epsilon$ is *always* in $X^*$ regardless of what $X$ is.

When $X = \emptyset$, there are no other strings in $X^*$, because you cannot take more than $0$ strings from $\emptyset$.  So the only string in $\emptyset^*$ is $\epsilon$: thus $\emptyset^* = \{\epsilon\}$.

Now let $X$ be some nonempty language, say $X = \{a\}$. Then $X^* = \{\epsilon, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, \ldots\}$.  Notice that $\epsilon$ is still in $X^*$, but now there are other strings because I can concatenate one or more $a$'s together.  The $\epsilon$ is what I get by concatenating zero $a$'s.

Comment: "When X=∅, there are no other strings in X∗, because you cannot take more than 0 strings from ∅. " -But, when X = {}, then X* should be X0 U X1 U X2 U.... We know that X0 is {} for any language. And, X1 = X = {}. Since X is an empty language so, any power of X will not generate any language. So, how come X* equals {eplison)? Correct me, please.

Comment: "We know that X0 is {} for any language": No!  $X_0 = \{ \epsilon \}$ for any language, because concatenating 0 strings produces the empty string.