# why start operating of empty language equal empty element?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

i am learning about compilation , analyse lexical and such things .

in something named rational expression ! it's something like regular expression there is a rule i can't understand it , i find it illogical !
the rule said that the start operating of empty language is the empty element .

[image]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908192/why-is-the-kleene-star-of-a-null-set-is-an-empty-string

Answer (score 1):

It is not the "start setting" but the star operation applied to the empty set. The result is indeed the set $\{\epsilon\}$. Look at the definition of the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) in wikipedia for more details.

Comment: thanks , i know it but i find't it illogical !
because how could we get an emty element from an empty language >?